# How can the html encoding for a text box be disabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ascx

I have some troubles with a text box input control value on an ascx page. It's value is somehow always html encoded, and I don't know how it can be disabled. 
For example when the value contains a `<` character it is always converted to `&lt;`. The strange thing is, it only happens on fields like `Name.Lastname` (which have a child property). My first thought was it could be caused by the Html extension method

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name.LastName, new { maxlength = "100" })
```

but this is not the case, because when I use the html input directly, it's value is still encoded:

```
<input id="Name_LastName" maxlength="100" 
       name="Name.LastName" 
       type="text" value="<%= Model.Name.LastName %>" />
```

Does somebody know how the html encoding of text box values for fields like `Name.LastName` (with a child property) can be disabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136944/automatically-htmlencode-in-asp-net

Comment: shouldn't you be using `<%:`?

Comment: you can use also Html.Raw(Model.Name.LastName)

Comment: The strange thing is that I also have a hidden input field which is also initialized with `Model.Name.LastName` and there it is not encoded and even when I use `<%= Model.Name.LastName %>` (not within an input field) I see the normal '<' character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found out that it was caused by a javascript function which variables were initialized using the `<%:`, and this function was used to initialize the text boxes. So in the end it had nothing to do with child properties. I changed the `<%:` with `<%=` in the javascript part:

`var lastName = "<%: Model.Name.LastName %>";`

in

`var lastName = "<%= Model.Name.LastName %>";`

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks but I had to wait for 2 hours to be able to do the accept ;)